# how to create leave one out cross validation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I am still confused with my code. I tried to implement leave one out cross validation in matlab for classification. so in here . I take out one data from training become testing data. I already make a code in matlab. but Iam not sure it's correct because the result is wrong. can someone help me to correct it?? thank you very much.

this is my code :

```
clc    
[C,F] = train('D:\fp\',...
    'D:\tp\');


for i=size(F,1)
testVal = i;      
trainingSet = setdiff(1:numel(C), testVal); % use the rest for training

Ctrain = C(trainingSet,:);
Ftrain = F(trainingSet,:);
test= F(testVal,:);
svmStruct = svmtrain(Ftrain,Ctrain,'showplot',true,'Kernel_Function','rbf');
result_class(i)= svmclassify(svmStruct,test,'showplot',true);
ax(i)=result_class;
i=i+1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually use to create leave one out cross-validation.

```
[Train, Test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut', N, M)
```

Here, `N` will be the number of total samples you have in your training+testing set. `M=1` in your case. You can put this in a for loop.

Also, you can use random number generation to perform leave-one out crossvalidation without using predefined function.